# .htaccess: respond to URL call with CGI

Tags: .htaccess

I have one file -- seminars.cgi -- that does all of the work in my app, including routing. (It's written as a CGI app in Go.) A typical call to it might look like this:

https://example.com/seminars.cgi/seminar/1234

I'm wondering whether there's any way I can use .htaccess to drop the seminars.cgi part, and instead have a call like this:

https://example.com/seminar/1234

My attempts have been futile:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^example.com/(.*?)$ example.com/seminars.cgi/$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

If I navigate to https://example.com/seminar/1234, the browser reports a 404, "Not found".

Any obvious issues?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try with below rule, I don't think that you need to specify domain name inside rule.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ seminars.cgi/$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I did learn one thing: my server doesn't like the 'L' or 'QSA' flags, nor does it like spaces after a comma. Once I got rid of all those, it came back with a 404 error: